# Relational database one to many relation

Tags: database, relational-database

I am using Access to create a database. I have two tables with the following data.

Car

```
CarID - PK
CarName
CarPrice
CustomerID
```

Customers

```
CustomerID -PK
Username
Password
CarID
```

I wish to have the relationship **as many cars to one customer**. Would I need a 3rd 'link' table or is there a way to do this without another table? Sorry for such a simple question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove CarID from your Customer table. Make CustomerID in the Car table a foreign key to Customer, and remove any existing unique constraints on that column.

Comment: I am still unsure which fields I should link together then. CarID in the car table to?

Comment: @joshuahornby10 Customer.CarID references Car.CarID. That's all you need. That will mean each car is assigned to a particular customer. Removing the car reference from the customer means that a customer is no longer assigned to a particular car. This creates the one to many relationship you want. What you have right now is a one to one relation. You would only need an additional table if you wanted a many to many relation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove CarID from your customers table and you would be set. Just be sure to have the CustomerID field in the Car table be a Foreign Key.